# Mongoose no longer accpet callback() MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: node.js, mongoose, findoneandupdate

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0ju7.png)

its says mongoose no longer accpet callback Model.findOne() no longer accept callback

Comment: Just a side note. There's absolutely no need to await `request.body`

Comment: You failed to show us where you used the `Model.findOne()` method

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
const query = Kitten.where({ color: 'white' });
const kitten = await query.findOne();
```